# in jstree dynamic menu how to make toggle links

Tags: javascript, jstree

I created a dynamic menu using jstree plugin, here my problem is to toggle the menu when we click on parent1 then the sub child will get opened and when i click on parent2 ie node two then i want to close the parent1.
How to implement this.

```
node1
    sub1
    sub2parent
          sub1
          sub2
          sub3
    sub3

node2
   sub1
   sub2
   sub3
```

here when i click on node one all sub are visible.
when i click on node 2 then the node1 sub nodes and note2 sub nodes are visible

what i need is when i click on node2 then node1 should get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `before_open` event and close all that are expanded by that moment.
Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/0Lgw2mr1/)

```
.on("before_open.jstree", function(e, data) {
   $('#tree').jstree().close_all();
});
```

Comment: this is working for one level but if there are multiple levels then it is not working all the main prent is getting closed when i click on sub parent which have more links.

Comment: So when you open a node what do you want to close ?

Comment: I got my requirment i used

Comment: .on("before_open.jstree", function(e, data) {
    var nodesToKeepOpen = [];

        // get all parent nodes to keep open
        $('#'+data.node.id).parents('.jstree-node').each(function() {
           nodesToKeepOpen.push(this.id);
        });

        // add current node to keep open
        nodesToKeepOpen.push( data.node.id );

        // close all other nodes
        $('.jstree-node').each( function() {
            if( nodesToKeepOpen.indexOf(this.id) === -1 ) {
                $("#tree").jstree().close_node(this.id);
            }
        })